# setBackground in View cannot be applied to (int)

Tags: java, android

Trying to set the background to the text.
The problem is the next error - setBackground in View cannot be applied to (int)

Here is my code

```
if (restaurants.get(position).getOffers() != null) {

        viewHolder.offerOrNew.setText("%");
        viewHolder.offerOrNew.setBackground(R.drawable.offers_style);
    }
```

The error is caused accordingly in this line

```
viewHolder.offerOrNew.setBackground(R.drawable.offers_style);
```

Comment: put your error log

Comment: I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the documentation and http://d.android.com. In particular, if you google the class name for your view such as `TextView`, `ImageView`, etc., you will find the documentation that describes every method fro that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `View.java` the method `setBackground()` signature is this:

```
public void setBackground(Drawable background)
```

so the argument must be a `Drawable` object and not a resource id.
You can use `setBackgroundResource()` instead:

```
viewHolder.offerOrNew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offers_style);
```